# How to accept text input in UserControl / ScrollableControl?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-2.0, textinput

I've created a canvas like control that draws images, shapes and text. Right now text can be added to the drawing surface only programmatically. But I would like to implement a more WYSIWYG-like text input method. So the basic idea is to capture keystrokes inside my ScrollableControl implementation.

This seems to be a trivial task - just override `OnKeyDown` method, right? Not quite :( This basically means that I'd have to manually handle all possible key combinations with SHIFT or ALT (for non-english alphabets).

So the question is: is there an easy way to do it? Note that not only text input is required, but also backspace, enter, cursor movement and all that stuff. I feel I'm missing something and manual input handling through `OnKeyDown` is not exactly the best solution.

Comment: No; it seems like a very difficult task.  I don't know why you think that would be trivial.

Comment: @SLaks, well usually difficult tasks seem difficult only until you know the proper way of doing them :)

Comment: The proper way to do it is extremely complicated, especially when you add IMEs, LTR, and accessibility.

Comment: WPF is not an option. I'm limited to .NET 2.0... but out of curiosity - how would WPF help?

Comment: WPF already did what you're trying to do - the re-implemented Windows text services. WPF textboxes cab be rotated.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want the text input to work, you can probably do it by adding a borderless textbox to your control and focusing it when the user starts typing.

Comment: using visible TextBox is not an option. Contents of my "canvas" can be scaled and rotated. I thought of using a hidden TextBox but I'm not sure if this is a right way to go. Besides, invisible TextBox can not receive focus, so keyboard input would have to be somehow passed from my control to the TextBox. How?

Comment: You could make a focused textbox positioned off Tue screen and mirror its text as you wish.

Comment: I've run some test and the TextBox outside of visible "canvas" seems to work quite well. There are some issues with reading cursor position, but this is a minor thing. However I'm going to hold on with accepting this answer as this is rather a hack and I'm hoping that someone can come up with more elegant solution.